# transformation of response variable which is in percentage

Tags: r, data-transformation, lme4-nlme, percentage

Here's my data.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/puf57efqkdl8zt0/data.csv?dl=0

It's too big, therefore I did not know to use the `dput(data)` command.

I am using a mixed effect model to model `response` as a function of 8 climate variables. `response` is derived from yield of 2 crops `yld.lc` and `yld.nc` as follows

response =  (yld.lc - yld.nc/yld.nc) * 100

Therefore response is in percentage and can be both negative and positive. In R, the package `lme4` can be used to run a mixed model as follows:

```
library(lme4)
mdl<-lmer(response ~ z.tx + I(z.tx^2) + z.ad + I(z.ad^2) + z.bd + I(z.bd^2) + z.dhs + I(z.dhs^2) + z.nwa + I(z.nwa^2) + z.tr + I(z.tr^2) + z.adr + I(z.adr^2) + z.nhs + I(z.nhs^2) + (1|site.code) + (1|year),data = yd.nc)
```

I have used the linear as well as quadratic term for all variables.

```
plot(mdl)
hist(resid(mdl)) # violation of model assumptions
qqnorm(resid(mdl)) # violation of model assumptions
qqline(resid(mdl)) # violation of model assumptions
```

How do I transform `response` which is in percentage as well as has both negative and positive percentage values so that my model assumptions are met?

Comment: Why do you think it needs transformation?

Comment: My residuals are not normally distributed and there is some evidence of heteroskedasticity. That is why I am want to transform my data.

Comment: You mention the least important (normal ...) and the second least important (homo...) ideal conditions for regression. Is there evidence that the linear structure is wrong (most important!)? Backing up, the asymmetry here needs a story. Why not (l - r) / r ? (l - r) / (l + r) might be better behaved. Can you post the data? Looks like you have `yld.l` `yld.r x1 x2` etc. I wouldn't assume that R notation is universally transparent outside an R-specific forum. I confess freely to not knowing what `1|rand1` means.

Comment: I have edited my question with the example data. Hopefully it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: The model and the notation have changed since the first posting. What's most obvious from a very quick look is massive variability (well over a hundred fold variation between min and max) and a suspicion that analysis on the logarithmic scale might be a good idea. As before full understanding of the model notation requires fluency in R.

Comment: I get wary if people have many predictors and consistently including quadratic terms. You should probably look into using a non-linear model, possibly a GAMM (see package mgcv).

Comment: Presumably there is a typo in what your write: (yld.lc - yld.nc/yld.nc) * 100 would seem to just be (yld.lc - 1) * 100?! Or do you mean (yld.lc - yld.nc)/yld.nc * 100 (i.e. you are looking for something like yld.nc is 10% larger than yld.lc, or in case of negative numbers smaller than)? If that's what you want, perhaps you should be analyzing log-transformed yld.lc with a log(yld.nc) offset?

Answer (score -1):

Things to consider or try:

- to deal with the negative values you might take the absolute value, but be wary of how interpretation changes if you do this
- using a nonparametric analysis that "fits" your data better (perhaps ordinal regression like "nnet"
- using a robust regression available in the "MASS" package to deal with violations of regression assumptions
- transforming your data with any number of functions (Manikandan provides a basic overview [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3043340/))

Comment: Absolute value sounds like a dubious idea in this case. I doubt that any agronomist (or farmer!) would regard {80 and 60} and {60 and 80} for two crop yields as equivalent.